# Raspberry Pi B+ serial port console garbage at boot

Tags: archlinux, serial-console

I am trying to login from Kubuntu 14.10 PC via `Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC` adapter with device id `0403:6001`. Now, I connect this adapter to rPi B+ GPIO port (RXD, TXT, GND) and connection is ok - triplechecked. Then I turn on minicom via `sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0` and instead of nice login screen I get garbage in minicom, which is demonstraed in screenshot. I've triplechecked port parameters in minicom, turned of software and hardware flow control, I did NOT modify `/boot/cmdline.txt` to disable console mode and it still does not work. What am I missing??[image: Serial Port Garbage]. And the second screenshot shows serial port config, which should be ok since rPi boots with `/dev/ttyAMA0 115200 8N1` port configuration[image: Serial Port Config]Well, I do not why, but after checking port parameters with 
`setserial` command:

```
[root@guidetest ~]# setserial -av /dev/ttyAMA0
/dev/ttyAMA0, Line 0, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 83
        Baud_base: 187500, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
        closing_wait: 3000
        Flags: spd_normal

[root@guidetest ~]#
```

the default baudrate is wrong. Is this maybe kernel/driver bug? I am using kernel `Linux guidetest 3.18.9-2-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Wed Mar 11 19:55:21 MDT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux`. I've checked the serial port parameters with `stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 -a` and here is output:
`speed 115200 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc
-ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt -echoctl -echoke`
Is here maybe something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that looks like the wrong baud rate.  The Pi boots with 115200 8N1.  Another check?

Comment: @joan I've upgraded question with screenshot of port settings.

Comment: Get a 'scope on the line.  There is so little to go wrong.  Check the ground is secure.

Comment: @joan I've checked ground with multimeter, it is secured.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  I've used a serial connection to the Pi boot many error free times at 115200 8N1.  One end is wrong.

Comment: `screen` can apparently be used here too, e.g., `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`.

Comment: @goldilocks I tried it now, same result, all meaningless garbage. I think I have to return to joans path, it must be something wrong with hardware/wiring.

Comment: I get the same output as you; I don't make any use of the serial line.  I *think* looking around that `Baud_base` indicates a *maximum* speed, which may be arbitrary since you can change it: `setserial /dev/ttyAMA0 baud_base 115200` works.  This doesn't affect the output from `stty` even if you make it less.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with the serial console. I have tried with cp210x and ftdi usb-to-serial converter, changed the baud rates too. I am getting the prints as first screenshot. Can you please share how you solved the problem. My understanding on your post is, I need to buy a serial pi adapter which is designed for pi 2 board only, other converters doesn't work. Please help me

Comment: @sukeshgowda which Raspberry Pi Model do you own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem: The cable is faulty and I did not use Serial Pi adapter. I've purchased them both, connected them and now the communication works without any problems!